# Move variable to cl and perform shr using inline assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, intel, inline-assembly

So I am trying to translate the following assignment from C to inline assembly

```
resp = (0x1F)&(letter >> (3 - numB));
```

Assuming that the declaration of the variables are the following

```
unsigned char resp;
unsigned char letter;
int numB;
```

So I have tried the following:

```
_asm {
        mov ebx, 01fh
        movzx edx, letter
        mov cl,3
        sub cl, numB // Line 5
        shr edx, cl
        and ebx, edx
        mov resp, ebx
}
```

or the following

```
_asm {
            mov ebx, 01fh
            movzx edx, letter
            mov ecx,3
            sub ecx, numB
            mov cl, ecx // Line 5
            shr edx, cl
            and ebx, edx
            mov resp, ebx
    }
```

In both cases I get size operand error in Line 5.
How can I achieve the right shift?

Comment: Have you looked at what a compiler will generate for this?

Comment: CL is the low byte of ECX.  Your second version looks right if you remove the nonsensical `mov cl, ecx`.  Since `numB` is 32 bits, you have to use it with 32-bit registers.  (Or maybe `sub cl, byte ptr numB` to only load the low byte, since SHR masks the shift count anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `E*X` registers are 32 bits, while the `*L` registers are 8 bits. Similarly, on Windows, the `int` type is 32 bits wide, while the `char` type is 8 bits wide. You cannot arbitrarily mix these sizes within a single instruction.

So, in your first piece of code:

```
sub cl, numB // Line 5
```

this is wrong because the `cl` register stores an 8-bit value, whereas the `numB` variable is of type `int`, which stores a 32-bit value. You cannot subtract a 32-bit value from an 8-bit value; both operands to the `SUB` instruction must be the same size.

Similarly, in your second piece of code:

```
mov cl, ecx // Line 5
```

you are trying to move the 32-bit value in ECX into the 8-bit CL register. That can't happen without some kind of truncation, so you have to indicate it explicitly. The `MOV` instruction requires that both of its operands have the same size.

(`MOVZX` and `MOVSX` are obvious exceptions to this rule that the operand types must match for a single instruction. These instructions zero-extend or sign-extend, respectively, a smaller value so that it can be stored into a larger-sized register.)

However, in this case, you don't even *need* the MOV instruction. Remember that CL is just the lower 8 bits of the full 32-bit ECX register. Therefore, setting ECX also implicitly sets CL. If you only need the lower 8 bits, you can just use CL in a subsequent instruction. Thus, your code becomes:

```
  mov   ebx, 01fh              ; move constant into 32-bit EBX
  movzx edx, BYTE PTR letter   ; zero-extended move of 8-bit variable into 32-bit EDX
  mov   ecx, 3                 ; move constant into ECX
  sub   ecx, DWORD PTR numB    ; subtract 32-bit variable from ECX
  shr   edx, cl                ; shift EDX right by the lower 8 bits of ECX
  and   ebx, edx               ; bitwise AND of EDX and EBX, leaving result in EBX
  mov   BYTE PTR resp, bl      ; move lower 8 bits of EBX into 8-bit variable
```

For the same operand-size matching issue discussed above, I've also had to change the final `MOV` instruction. You cannot move the value stored in a 32-bit register directly into an 8-bit variable. You will have to move either the lower 8 bits or the upper 8 bits, allowing you to use either the `BL` or `BH` registers, which are 8 bits and therefore match the size of `resp`. In the above code, I assumed that you want only the lower 8 bits, so I've used `BL`.

Also note that I've used the `BYTE PTR` and `DWORD PTR` specifications. These are not strictly necessary in MASM (or Visual Studio's inline assembler), since it can deduce the sizes of the types from the types of the variables. However, I think it increases readability, and is generally a recommended practice. `DWORD` means 32 bit; it is the same size as `int` and a 32-bit register (`E*X`). `WORD` means 16 bit; it is the same size as `short` and a 16-bit register (`*X`). `BYTE` means 8 bits; it is the same size as `char` and an 8-bit register (`*L` or `*H`).